# Looking for a good MySQL editor for Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, editor

As funny as it is, most good MySQL editors are Windows based.
I am looking for a tool (US$400 top) for Ubuntu that can:

- Auto complete tables and fields names + reserved keywords.
- syntax coloring.
- inline row content edit.
- copy tables/databases from one host to an other.

I think the best Windows based is [SQLyog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLyog), but it is a nightmare working on [Wine](http://www.webyog.com/en/screenshots.php?ref=2).

Comment: Why nightmare. 5 of my colleagues and me are using SqlYog on Ubuntu via wine.

Comment: I am using HeidiSQL via wine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I highly recommend [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/).  It's a Java application and runs on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.  The MySQL JDBC driver is bundled in the package.

[image: DbVisualizer Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, nice but it has no functionality for copping tables and databases between hosts and no auto complete. thanks again

Comment: It has every feature you requested except direct copying between hosts.  You can accomplish the copying with a simple export/import.

Comment: From the home page - "SQL editor with support for auto completion..."

Comment: ok. saw it, great tool thanks

Comment: a sql editor running on Linux with a dark theme out of the box - all i needed.

Answer (score 2):

you might look at these sql clients below, all of them are open-source:

- http://www.sql-workbench.net
- http://executequery.org